# Error using array_push

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I am trying to use array_push but I am recieving error messages like:

Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\Users\DMR\Google Drive\android\maquetas\show.php on line 50

in two linews where I am using array_push, I don't understand why, could you help me please? the code is the next:

```
...

$etiquetes = array("N.I.F.", "Direcció");
$tipus = array("varchar", "varchar");
$columnes = array("CIF_NIF", "DIRECCION");
$llongituds = array(30, 30);

...

$i=0;
foreach ($etiquetes as $etiqueta) {
    $control = array_push($etiqueta, $columnes[$i], $tipus[$i], $llongituds[$i]);       <==== IT GIVE ME ERROR (ATTACHED AT THE END)
    $controls[$i % 2] = array_push($control); <==== IT GIVE ME ERROR (ATTACHED AT THE END)

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: read the warning message? $etiquata is a string, you're supposed to use $etiquets (because it's an array)

Comment: What are you trying to do in that loop?  What are `$control` and `$controls`?

Comment: Read the manual on [`array_push`](http://php.net/array_push). First parameter needs to be an array. It isn't. Reconsider what your code does. If you want help, curb the annoying pleas for help and instead elaborate on what your code was intended to to.

Comment: I mistook the using of I array i dind't read the right format for array_push. Thanks. I read manual again maybe I thjought in another language the use of push... typical error

Answer (score 2):

`$etiqueta` is not an array thus

```
 array_push($etiqueta, ...
```

is wrong. You might be looking for:

```
 array_push($etiquetes, ...
```

Also, from array_push() docs:

> Returns the new number of elements in the array.

Which means $control will have an **int** value. So you second line

```
array_push($control);
```

Is ofcourse invalid, I would suggest you [look at the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) and try to figure out what are you planning to do.

Comment: $etiquetes, .. is the array and I want the value inside the array for this reason I used foreach. But ... thanks becuase I rereaded again about array_push and I saw my error.

Comment: `$control = array(array(), array(), array(), array());
array_push($control, $etiqueta, $columnes[$i], $tipus[$i], $llongituds[$i]);  

array_push($controls[$i % 2], $control); `

Comment: It is working, I saw the error in the tutorial. As I said a litle mistake from me

Answer (score 0):

Here it is better to answer because it will be more clear for all of you (I hope)

I will explain here my solution, I have two DIV left and right and I have n controls in the array, what I am trying to do is when I loopp in the array I set the impair in the left and the pais in the right, for this reason I used the bucle:

```
foreach ($etiquetes as $etiqueta) {
     $control = array(array(), array(), array(), array());
     array_push($control, $etiqueta, $columnes[$i], $tipus[$i], $llongituds[$i]);       
     array_push($controls[$i % 2], $control);       

     $i++;
}
```

Now I have it it will be easy to set in the html code. The code I set before $columnes will be the fields of the table in the database and $etiquetes will be the label.

then I will need to put the length, type for the input fields, etc...

then the screen will be wllformed.

I hope it can be more clear for you. Now code I wrote here it is working just I have to put performance.